# Add a class when the component is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add a class to my input only when the component is updated, not when it is mounted. So, every time when I will start to write in the input, I want to add the class: `demo`.

```js
const App = () => {
  function Change(e) {
    setState(e.target.value);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
   document.getElementById('test').classList.add("demo")
  }, []);
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  return (
      <div className="main">\sd
        <input id='test' onChange={Change} type="text"/>
        <p>{state}</p>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

How to do this using my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend mapping your requirements more directly to the code instead of trying to hack the behavior of `useEffect`. Additionally, I'd avoid doing DOM manipulations instead of just doing things with React, since there's no guarantee the same DOM element will be preserved across renders:

```
const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ hasEdited: false, value: '' });
  return (
    <div className="main">
      <input 
        id='test' 
        type="text"
        className={state.hasEdited ? 'demo' : ''}
        onChange={e => setState({ ...state, hasEdited: true, value: e.target.value })}
      />
      <p>{state.value}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```